# Which Lubuntu services could I block, without breaking the OS ? Just for security reasons

Tags: lubuntu, services

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      496/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      108062/cupsd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      108062/cupsd        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           496/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           108063/cups-browsed 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43546           0.0.0.0:*                           506/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           108351/chrome       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           506/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::6666                 :::*                                1242/qlipper        
udp6       0      0 :::34940                :::*                                506/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                506/avahi-daemon: r
```

.

```
sudo killall cupsd
```

.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      496/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           496/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           108063/cups-browsed 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43546           0.0.0.0:*                           506/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           108351/chrome       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           506/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::6666                 :::*                                1242/qlipper        
udp6       0      0 :::34940                :::*                                506/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                506/avahi-daemon: r
```

.

```
sudo ss -tulp
Netid     State      Recv-Q     Send-Q         Local Address:Port            Peer Address:Port     Process                                                                                            
udp       UNCONN     0          0              127.0.0.53%lo:domain               0.0.0.0:*         users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=496,fd=12))                                                         
udp       UNCONN     0          0                    0.0.0.0:631                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("cups-browsed",pid=108063,fd=7))                                                          
udp       UNCONN     0          0                    0.0.0.0:43546                0.0.0.0:*         users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=506,fd=14))                                                            
udp       UNCONN     0          0                224.0.0.251:mdns                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("chrome",pid=108351,fd=191))                                                              
udp       UNCONN     0          0                    0.0.0.0:mdns                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=506,fd=12))                                                            
udp       UNCONN     0          0                          *:6666                       *:*         users:(("qlipper",pid=1242,fd=13))                                                                
udp       UNCONN     0          0                       [::]:34940                   [::]:*         users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=506,fd=15))                                                            
udp       UNCONN     0          0                       [::]:mdns                    [::]:*         users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=506,fd=13))                                                            
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096           127.0.0.53%lo:domain               0.0.0.0:*         users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=496,fd=13))
```

Just for security reasons.
Because I will never use the printer for this system, how to completely block the cupsd service forever, so it will not let port 631 port beeing exploitable?
Are these the right command?

```
systemctl mask cupsd
systemctl disable cups.service cups.socket cups.path
```

Because I am not so advanced, could these commands make more damages for the OS then helping it being more secure?

What about `avahi-daemon` and `qlipper`, are these services vital for the OS, or could them be blocked completely, forever?

```
systemctl --reverse list-dependencies avahi-daemon.service
avahi-daemon.service
● ├─cups-browsed.service
● └─multi-user.target
●   └─graphical.target
```

.

```
systemctl --reverse list-dependencies qlipper.service
qlipper.service
```

EDIT:

Done it:

```
killall cupsd avahi-daemon qlipper
systemctl mask cupsd avahi-daemon qlipper
systemctl disable cups.service cups.socket cups.path cups-browsed.service multi-user.target graphical.target qlipper
```

Now:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      496/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           496/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           108388/chrome --typ 
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           108351/chrome
```

Regards.

Comment: If you are never, ever going to use CUPS, you can uninstall it.

Comment: Thank you for your replay @user535733 If CUPS is regarding only about the physical printer, I am never not going to use it.

Comment: I was actually surprised to see `qlipper` in netstat output... (*as were others in chat on *Lubuntu* IRC*), but I can't see any issues if it was stopped.  The manual tells you how to re-start it if required (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/2/2.4/2.4.5/Qlipper.html), and the start is visible & easily disabled/deleted (in "*Application Autostart*" under "*LXQt Autostart*").  You didn't provide a release, so I'm basing it on my own.

Comment: As for `avahi-daemon`, do you use it on your network? or is the machine stand-alone? and you don't access other devices on your local network exp. via zeroconf (easy) methods. You haven't provided enough details as to how you use your machine to know if you'll miss it.  I used a `avahi-browser` command to explore my own local network, and I wouldn't miss it; but your usage may differ to my own.  I experienced no consequences, but again I don't use anything it provides...

Comment: Further to my prior `qlipper` comment; the networking feature is "experimental" (https://github.com/pvanek/qlipper/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L50) and maybe disabled (turned off) in Lubuntu in the future... but discussions are still on-going (lubuntu *devs* on IRC)

Comment: re: `qlipper` : networking was enabled in Debian (https://salsa.debian.org/lxqt-team/qlipper/-/commit/a842f39cb3ea7cccd2f919a370babb29ae1b71e6) & change flowed thru to us

Comment: Lubuntu is now maintainer of `qlipper` (rather than using Debian's package), and we've turned off networking.. (which we consider *best practices*).. You didn't specify a release, but development is *hirsute* so that's where it'll take effect.

Answer (score 0):

**avahi-daemon**

With regards `avahi-daemon`, do you use it on your network? or is the machine stand-alone? and you don't access other devices on your local network exp. via zeroconf (easy) methods. You haven't provided enough details as to how you use your machine to know if you'll miss it. I used a `avahi-browser` command to explore my own local network, and I wouldn't miss it; but your usage may differ to my own. I experienced no consequences with it stopped, but again I don't use anything it provides.

**qlipper**

I was actually surprised to see `qlipper` in `netstat` output... (as were others in chat on *Lubuntu IRC*), but I can't see any issues if it was stopped. The manual tells you how to re-start it if required (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/2/2.4/2.4.5/Qlipper.html), and the start is visible & easily disabled/deleted (in "*Application Autostart*" under "*LXQt Autostart*").

You didn't provide a release, so I'm basing it on my own (*testing on two releases actually*)

The networking feature is "experimental" (https://github.com/pvanek/qlipper/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L50) and maybe disabled (*turned off*) in Lubuntu in the future... but discussions are still on-going (*lubuntu devs on IRC*)

Networking was enabled in *upstream* Debian (https://salsa.debian.org/lxqt-team/qlipper/-/commit/a842f39cb3ea7cccd2f919a370babb29ae1b71e6) & change flowed thru to us.

Lubuntu is now maintainer of `qlipper` (*rather than using Debian's package*), and we've turned off networking.. (which we consider *best practices*).. You didn't specify a release, but development is *hirsute* currently so that's where the change I'm talking about will take effect.

Thanks for alerting us to the *rabbit hole* that `qlipper` had become.

Most thanks to @wxl who did ~95% of the work :)

---

*this 'answer' is mostly just comments made above. had you specified a release, I'd have confined my comments to that release, instead I've used whatever was handy which includes focal, groovy & hirsute*

Comment: Thank you @guiverc, I have just edited the main question, Hopefully the system will not become unstable.  Regards.

Comment: But, after reboot, qlipper is alive again: `udp6       0      0 :::6666                 :::*                                1232/qlipper `

Comment: After the reboot, because qlipper was still alive, I `killall` `mask` `disable` qlipper again, and restart again. and qlipper is still here for the `nestat`: `udp6       0      0 :::6666                 :::*                                1227/qlipper `

Comment: I think  that now qlipper is gone: `sudo apt-get purge qlipper`

Comment: You didn't say how you disabled `qlipper`, it's started as per the manual (unless you changed it as you explored your system and made package changes), so I'd expect the unchecking of the box to stop it. If it doesn't you can submit a bug report and I'll take a look (test it & find the issue)...

Comment: Thank you @guiverc. I decided to keep using qlipper. Regards.